# GMail API Quickstart c# failure HttpListener exception

Tags: c#, api, gmail

I am trying to get started with the Gmail APIs so that I can create new users via the APIs.  I found the .Net Quickstart program on the Google developer's site and followed all the instructions.  The program is failing on the GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync call line with this error:

> System.AggregateException: HttpListenerException:  The network location cannot be reached.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 version 15.9.14.  One would think that the canned demo code would work as written.

Thanks in advance to any/all that can help solve this.

Here is the code block:

```
 UserCredential credential;

        using (var stream =
            new FileStream("credentials.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is created
                // automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first time.
                string credPath = "token.json";

                credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                    GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                    Scopes,
                    "user",
                    CancellationToken.None,
                    new FileDataStore(credPath, true)).Result;
                Console.WriteLine("Credential file saved to: " + credPath);
            }
```

```
Here is the stack trace:
 at System.Net.HttpListener.AddAllPrefixes()
   at System.Net.HttpListener.Start()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.StartListener()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.LocalServerCodeReceiver.<ReceiveCodeAsync>d__16.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp.<AuthorizeAsync>d__8.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable`1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.<AuthorizeAsync>d__1.MoveNext()
```

Contents of credentials.json file:
[Contents of credentials.json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSyYD.png)

Comment: The credentials should be included as text in the question instead of posting an image of it.